# IE 10 does not re-apply padding on text-inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an IE 10 specific issue concerning text-inputs and padding that gives me a lot of headache. Here's a textual description of the setup and of what is happening but there is also a running example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/41nq3pt1/5/

I've omitted the CSS below, because it's a bit larger, please look at the JSFiddle. Help is really appreciated and I'm not only looking for a solution but also for an explanation why IE 10 is behaving weird.

## Description

This is the HTML structure of my input element:

```
<div class="input">
  <label class="input__label" for="input">Floating label</label>
  <input class="input__input" type="text" id="input">
</div>
```

**Initial State:** In the initial state of the input field, there is an absolutely positioned label centered in the vertical middle of the `input`. This is done by giving it a `padding-top`. The padding of the input itself is adjusted so that the blinking cursor appears on the same height as the label.

**Input has content:** When typing something in the field, the label is moved upwards by reducing its `padding-top` while simultaneously increasing the input's `padding-top` to move it downward a little. Alternating the padding is done by adding a class via Javascript:

```
// jQuery 1.12.4
$('.input__input').on('keyup input', function() {
  if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).closest('.input').removeClass('input--has-content');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.input').addClass('input--has-content');
  }
});
```

**After deleting content:** When the input is found to be empty, the class that alters the padding is removed and the input should be in its initial state. Now, despite working in all current browsers even down to IE 8 (I didn't test older versions), **IE 10 apparently does not change the padding of the `input` element back**, see this screenshot: [IE 10 vs. other browsers after step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeHLJ.png).

## Steps to reproduce

1. Click into the input field, see the cursor blinking on the same line as the label
2. Type something, the label should move upwards, the cursor moves slightly downwards
3. Remove every input by hitting backspace
4. The label moves down again and the cursor should blink on the same line as in step 1.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This may have to do with the height being set and how IE10 handles the padding. You could try experimenting with using: box-sizing: border-box; Also, you could try absolute/relative positioning instead as well as line-height to adjust the offsets, to see if you can achieve progress in IE10.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I've done some testing with line-heights and came to a solution that involves a transparent border: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38072818/5695127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Marks comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057020/ie-10-does-not-re-apply-padding-on-text-inputs#comment63554750_38057020), I experimented a bit with line-heights and eventually came to a solution that doesn't rely on line-heights but solves the problem by using a transparent border.

**Solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/41nq3pt1/16/

Instead of increasing the `padding-top` of the input when it has content, I set the height from `5rem` to `4rem` and give it a transparent `border-top`. This seems to work in all major browsers (tested in IE 9, 10, 11, Edge and the current Chrome, Firefox, Safari). Here is the important code block with annotations:

```
.input__input {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem; // set a fixed height
  padding-left: 1rem; // removed padding-top
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.input--has-content .input__input {
  border-top: 1rem solid transparent; // replaced padding-top
  height: 4rem; // keep total height at 5rem
}
```

I would still like to know why the original version didn't work in IE 10 but – *oh well* – I'm happy that I've found a fix that isn't too hacky.